# Sharepoint sites/pages/documents viewed by the current user, Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, web-services

I need to gather information about the current logged in user

- All recent **Documents viewed** (hyperlink)(throughout SP, includes one or many site collections)
- All recent **Links navigated**

best case using **client object model**, else server object model.

I highly appreciate anyone providing ideas/solutions.

Thank you

Comment: For current logged in session only or entire history?

Comment: for current logged in.... by the day/week not complete history

Comment: You may find this link useful: http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint_blank/archive/2008/12/05/tracking-sharepoint-site-users-and-their-site-usage.aspx